# Magento 1.7.0.2 Pending Payment status- after successful payment in Paypal

Tags: magento

I have magneto website where various online goods are being sold. I have set up PayPal Website Payments Standard in admin section with PayPal account details is already activated.

When client successfully place the order and paid the bill with PayPal, I got "Pending Payment" status in order details page in admin. Actually order has been processed and PayPal accept the payment.

My question is why "Pending Payment" is showing in admin even payment has bee successfully proceed.

Comment: Just get in touch with paypal support, they have an update to solve this bug

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how Paypal/Magento payment processing work, and not programming.

Answer (score 5):

The latest PayPal integration changed the order processing schema (from PayPal side). Now there are no results being returned to Magento after you successfully paid for the order. Instead store owner should configure PayPal IPN feature.

Unfortunately the link to configure PayPal IPN is no longer on the Magento wiki. Here's the link to the PayPal docs (which is the majority of the config required): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Magento IPN receiver would be something like: http://www.yoursitename.com/index.php/paypal/ipn/index/ - use your real domain. That should go into the Notification URL config in your PP acc.

Comment: The guide that you provided does not match with current version of Magneto 1.7.0.2. So please submit another solutions.

Comment: the link is not showing paypal related document, please update the link.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your reply. I finally figured it out. There can be three possible cause of the error:

1. Check you merchant location in magento admin from system->configuration->payment method. Merchant location and Paypal business account country location should be same. This seemed to be the problem with me. I had merchant locations set as UK and my sandbox accound seller account was US.
2. It may not be send IPN. Login to paypal sandbox website and under history section there is an option for IPN enable it from there
3. In your paypal sandbox account, going into profile->setting->payment review and turn it off.

Comment: I am using CCAvenue Payment Gateway, i have frequently faced this issue. May i know what are all the possibilities of error.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a programming question please make sure you have set "`Payment Action`" to "`Sale`" in the `Magento` administration area.

You can find this under `System -> Configuration -> Payment Methds -> PayPal Payment Solutions tab`

Comment: Sorry this do not help. Please do another solutions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **Slayer Birden** : "The latest PayPal integration changed the order processing schema (from PayPal side)".

The guide does seem to be outdated.
However For IPN settings you need to log in to your PayPal account and go to **`Profile->My selling Tools`**. Here you can find Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) settings.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution

Try to set “Transfer Cart Line Items” to No under configuration->payment methods->PayPal.

If it works for you then let me know!

Found on:
http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/magento-17-issue-with-a-paypal-payments-order-92356.html

Answer (score 0):

My client had merchant account from Hongkong and we were using Website Hosting Pro as payment solution as Paypal has no provision to make payments from website itself except (US,UK and Canada).

This is hardcoded in magento , I did not understand why.?

To setup paypal with your account,

In your website folder go to ,
    (version used here was ver 1.7.0.2)
        {your installation folder}/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model

open file "HostedPro.php"

In bottom , you will find function ,

```
public function getNotifyUrl($storeId = null)
{
    return $this->_getUrl('paypal/ipn', $storeId, false);
}
```

This function sets ipn value for Hosting Pro. 
Similarlly you can find ipn values afor other payment
methods(express,standard,etc..) in this folder.
Either change this to your desired value as set in paypal account
or change it from these(magento) files.
I chose first option and it worked. 
After this your orders status should get changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension : [Magento Order Repay Extension](http://www.54dev.com/product/magento-repay)